# Migrating from Firefox WebDriver to Marionette

Tags: selenium, webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am trying to switch from FireFoxDriver to MarionetteDriver.
I managed to run firefox with MarionetteDriver by running:

```
public void runMarionnete(){
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    OSUtils.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    OSUtils.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Drivers\\wires-0.6.2-win.exe"));
    _driver = new MarionetteDriver(dc);
}
```

But I have 2 things I am not sure how to do:

1.How to add XPI extensions to the driver ? 
in the old way I used:
FirefoxProfile.addExtension ...

2.How to configure all the firefox properties , like I used to do , for example:

```
    profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage;about:home","about:blank");
    profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url","about:blank");
    profile.setPreference("browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL","about:blank");
    profile.setPreference("devtools.devedition.promo.url","");
    profile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required",false);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same FirefoxProfile class, just add it to the DesiredCapabilities in the following way:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage;about:home","about:blank");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url","about:blank");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL","about:blank");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("devtools.devedition.promo.url","");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required",false);

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
```

Comment: I wonder if there's any more to this.  I tried adding to capabilities, but setting the download directory and auto download still didn't work for me.

Comment: I am also have trouble with the auto download--has there been an update to this? Here is my code:


`fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`
`fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "H:\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir","H:\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder","H:\Downloads")`



`driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities,firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile = fp)`


Am I missing something?

Comment: I came across this thread: [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/236) which eventually ends with this thread: [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2572). The latter thread seems to be the most recent discussion on this matter. I asked how to update my code, and will make an update to this thread when it is figured it out.